# Xamarin Not installing correctly

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

So I'm trying to install Xamarin to do some Android dev with Visual Studio, but once I have installed Xamarin, or at least the installer claims it has installed, I go into VS and do New Project - Blank Android App, and after a few moments, it Gives an error that can be seen here:

[image: Error after creating project]

This is the full error log from the Xamarin Diagnostics console: http://pastebin.com/QcfCi60N

So from this, I'm getting that most if not all of the components required for Xamarin haven't been installed. Why aren't they installing? I tried running the installer again, and after it again said it had installed successfully installed, I tried again and it just gave the same error.

What can I do to install Xamarin properly? is there some other package I need to get instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to BytesGuy you might have installed the Android SDK in a custom path. Try checking if the SDK location has changed in your settings to default.

Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are missing the Android SDK. Not sure if this is directly related to the error message shown, but it wouldn't harm to try installing the Android SDK and re-install Xamarin.

Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe

Xamarin: http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.3.214.msi

Comment: Awesome news @MattyAB !  Please accept one of the answers when you can :)